# Blackberry receiving old messages.

Tags: email, exchange, blackberry

One of our people keep complaining of getting old messages on their blackberry. Some of the messages are from 2007.

They are using BIS server and we have checked all of the settings are correct.

They are also getting 3-5 per week, most from 2007!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resending the service books?

Answer (score 0):

When I reported a similar problem a few years ago, I was advised to delete the mail account from the BlackBerry and then set it up again, letting the handheld re-synchronize with my IMAP mail account. (This was using T-Mobile's service, not a BES.)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this several times and couldn't find a reasonable answer. I noticed however, if the users have sync issues (in outlook sync folder) then this started happening. Double check the "WIN Rule" on the devices (mailbox wins).

Answer (score 0):

If the BIS detects the mail as new it will resend it.  So if you have backup software, anti-virus, etc that is changing messages that could trigger BIS to think it's a new email and resend it. I've also seen the Exchange POP3 service not play nicely in general if that's your mail server.